# Disable/enable children of container when using progress indicator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have on a page a progress indicator, and as long as it is charging, all the controls on page are disabled, and when the spinner finishes loading all the controls are enabled.

So my question is :

If I have a control in that page that is disabled before I set disable on all the children of the container(when the spinner is loading), what can I do to keep the state:"disabled" for it when the progress indicator finishes(when I set enable to the children of container).

Comment: Is there need for code? The question is clear without it.

Comment: Does this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/GRrL7/) replicate the above behaviour?